# Change currency according to customer group

Tags: customer, currency, group

My base currency is USD. I want to change according to customer-group i.e. If customer group "Retailer" the currency =EUR.

So far I managed to get customer's group code:

```
$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId)->getCustomerGroupCode();

if($customer == 'Retailer') { /* Change currency to EUR */ }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try to use this solution http://ohnorandom.com/161-magento-switch-currency-based-on-customer-group/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an observer and set currency is below way. You just have to set your customer group ID here: `if ($groupId == 1)`

> app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </my_module>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <change_currency>
                        <class>my_module/observer</class>
                        <method>changeCurrency</method>
                    </change_currency>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class My_Module_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer
{
    public function changeCurrency(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        if ($groupId == 1) {
            Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('EUR');
        } else {
            Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode('USD');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Had the same idea ... but was to slow :P

Comment: Thats good sv3n. But I try to give logic to user not the whole code. Don't have all time to write there peace of code :)

Comment: I understand. But if it results in question where to put the code it possbly takes more time :)

Comment: How do I know what observer event I have to use? Why controller_action_predispatch ?

Comment: Could you explain the difference between if($groupId == 1) and if($groupName == 'Retailer') ?

Comment: You can consider `controller_action_predispatch` as the first event dispatched in magento. Although there are few others. So It will check your customer group and set the currency in store front runtime. You can also check this event `controller_front_init_before`.

Comment: I did some debug and it works with that event but unfortunately it doesn't change the currency

Comment: Is Euro set in allowed currency list

Comment: It wasn't! But now it works, thank you!